# How can I fix this jQuery Ajax rendering issue in a Rails 2.3.8 app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to do cascading dependent select boxes using jQuery. I have the following in a file called "get_descriptions.js.erb", which gets called just fine:

```
<% fields_for :person do |f| %>
    $("#descriptiondiv .floater:first").html("<%= f.select :description, @person.descriptions.map_by_person_type %>");
<% end %>
```

I can see in Firebug that the appropriate response is indeed returned, but nothing shows on the screen. Here is the exact response as reported in Firebug, with no errors:

```
$("#descriptiondiv .floater:first").html("<select id="person_description" name="person[description]"><option value="Employee">Employee</option></select>");
```

That response does *not* show up on the browser.

However, if I just do this:

```
<% fields_for :person do |f| %>
    $("#descriptiondiv .floater:first").html("hello world");
<% end %>
```

then "hello world" does indeed appear where I expect it to.

Why is my select box not rendering on screen, but "hello word" is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a quoting problem to me, try adding an `escape_javascript`:

```
<% fields_for :person do |f| %>
    $("#descriptiondiv .floater:first").html("<%= escape_javascript f.select :description, @person.descriptions.map_by_person_type %>");
<% end %>
```

Or just `j`:

```
<% fields_for :person do |f| %>
    $("#descriptiondiv .floater:first").html("<%= j f.select :description, @person.descriptions.map_by_person_type %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Jackpot, thanks! I took another look at the response and saw those quotes.